# Показ времени в соответствии с режимом работы сервиса

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, время, momentjs

Есть сервис, у сервиса есть время работы, необходимо в соответствии со настройками времени работы показывать время открытия и закрытия сервиса (пример что есть и что должно получиться - ниже)

НА ВХОДЕ:

Настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройка одного дня (пример)

weekDay:
1: 'понедельник,
2: 'вторник',
3: 'среда',
4: 'четверг',
5: 'пятница',
6: 'суббота',
0: 'воскресенье'

```
workingHours = [
              {
                    'open_weekday': 1,
                    'close_weekday': 2,
                    'open_hours': 12,
                    'close_hours': 4,
                    'open_minutes': 0,
                    'close_minutes': 0,
                    'enabled': true,
                }, ...
]
```

НА ВЫХОДЕ:
Что нужно получить:

```
Понедельник: c 12:00 - 00:00
Вторник: c 00:00 - 04:00 , c 12:00 - 17:00
Среда: с 09:00 - 21:00
Четверг: с 09:00 - 13:00, c 14:00 - 21:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

, я преобразовал часы работы в задании в удобный формат через `.map`. После я передал дни недель в виде, который нужен Вам.

```js
const weekDays = {
  1: 'Понедельник',
  2: 'Вторник',
  3: 'Среда',
  4: 'Четверг',
  5: 'Пятница',
  6: 'Суббота',
  0: 'Воскресенье'
};

const workingHours = [{
  'open_weekday': 1,
  'close_weekday': 2,
  'open_hours': 12,
  'close_hours': 4,
  'open_minutes': 0,
  'close_minutes': 0,
  'enabled': true
}, {
  'open_weekday': 2,
  'close_weekday': 2,
  'open_hours': 12,
  'close_hours': 17,
  'open_minutes': 0,
  'close_minutes': 0,
  'enabled': true
}, {
  'open_weekday': 3,
  'close_weekday': 3,
  'open_hours': 9,
  'close_hours': 21,
  'open_minutes': 0,
  'close_minutes': 0,
  'enabled': true
}, {
  'open_weekday': 4,
  'close_weekday': 4,
  'open_hours': 9,
  'close_hours': 13,
  'open_minutes': 0,
  'close_minutes': 0,
  'enabled': true
}, {
  'open_weekday': 4,
  'close_weekday': 4,
  'open_hours': 14,
  'close_hours': 21,
  'open_minutes': 0,
  'close_minutes': 0,
  'enabled': true
}];

function getWorkingHours(workingHours, weekDays) {
  return workingHours.map(workingHour => {
    if (workingHour.open_weekday !== workingHour.close_weekday) {
      return [{
        day: weekDays[workingHour.open_weekday],
        open: `${`${workingHour.open_hours}`.padStart(2, 0)}:${`${workingHour.open_minutes}`.padStart(2, 0)}`,
        close: `00:00`
      }, {
        day: weekDays[workingHour.close_weekday],
        open: `00:00`,
        close: `${`${workingHour.close_hours}`.padStart(2, 0)}:${`${workingHour.close_minutes}`.padStart(2, 0)}`
      }]
    }
    return {
      day: weekDays[workingHour.open_weekday],
      open: `${`${workingHour.open_hours}`.padStart(2, 0)}:${`${workingHour.open_minutes}`.padStart(2, 0)}`,
      close: `${`${workingHour.close_hours}`.padStart(2, 0)}:${`${workingHour.close_minutes}`.padStart(2, 0)}`
    }
  }).flat().map((time, index, array) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      return `${time.day}: с ${time.open} - ${time.close}`;
    } else if (array[index - 1].day == time.day) {
      return `, с ${time.open} - ${time.close}`;
    } else {
      return `\n${time.day}: с ${time.open} - ${time.close}`
    };
  }).join('');
};

console.log(getWorkingHours(workingHours, weekDays));
```